# How to run another activity in a customized activity of TFS 2012 build process template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity, build-process-template

I'm writing a customized activity for TFS build process workflow, e.g. guideline [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx).

In my C# CodeActivity .Execute() method, I want to run another activity, e.g. `ConvertWorkspaceItem` as descibed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing some research with a **NativeActivity** instead of a CodeActivity, so the execution context allows you to schedule other child activities.
E.g.:

```
class YourActivity : NativeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        ConvertWorkspaceItem it = new ConvertWorkspaceItem();
        context.ScheduleActivity(it);
    }
}
```