# How to get path to file path in a Workspace by C# in a customized activity of TFS 2012 build process template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity, build-process-template

I'm writing a customized activity for TFS build process workflow, e.g. guideline [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx).

In my C# CodeActivity .Execute() method, I want to get path to file and/or folder in a Workspace
I tried google and found `ConvertWorkspaceItem` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't know how to run it and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092460/how-to-run-another-activity-in-a-customized-activity-of-tfs-2012-build-process-t).

If you know how to, please share.

Comment: I think what I mean is item, not work item @Saunders

Answer (score 1):

The ConvertWorkspaceItem is an activity. In your custom code activity, you can either create an instance of this activity, set the required parameters and call the `Execute()` method. Or you can use the `VersionControlServer.TryGetWorkspace` and which returns a Workspace object. Use `Workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem` or the reverse `Workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem`.